# Why do we use invoke operator overloading in Kotlin Usecases?

Tags: android, kotlin, operator-overloading

I've started using use-cases in kotlin for clean coding practices but not clear why we use the invoke operator overloading.
What's the point and why not call it execute() instead?

```
interface GetUserUseCase {
    operator fun invoke(): Single<Result<User>>
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use invoke operator on UseCase provides some benefits:

- Enforces a pseudo-contract on a contract-less UseCase
- Reads more naturally
- Flexibility in invocation ( loginUseCase() vs loginUseCase.invoke() )